# Is it possible to install CyanogenMod for "Samsung GS4" on a "Samsung GS4 Active" device?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-4, rom

As I was desperately waiting for the 4.4 update on my Samsung Galaxy S4 Active, I read that Cyanogenmod was available for the Samsung Galaxy S4.

My problem is: Is it possible to install the CyanogenMod ROM for the Samsung Galaxy S4 (GT-I9205) on my Samsung Galaxy S4 Active (GT-I9295)?

NB: The GT-I9295 is more or less the same as the GT-I9205, but has physical buttons. So I assumed that the drivers (and the ROM) could be different, but I'm new to Android ROM hacking.

Comment: It has to be for your EXACT device. For example the GT19505 (international S4) and the GTi9505G are exactly the same hardware one is google edition, one is samsung touchwiz. The ROM from one is NOT compatible with the other without it being modified, and never will. I'd be 99.9% certain you'll brick your device.

Comment: Done! If you need anything else just let me know! Glad you asked before trying it! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually an important question, and far better to ask now than try it and be stuck with a blank screen!

Android ROMs are specific to the device. This is why CyanogenMod and others have the specific device model and code name on them.

Even in cases where the deveice looks and feels the same and has the same name e.g. Samsung Galaxy S4:

> GT-I9505
>
> GT-I9500

They both run Android 4.4 now, and they look and to all user purposes are the same device. Under the hood there are differences, and no ROM will be compatible between the two.

I had used the Google Edition S4 as my example as ROMS weren't compatible between two devices with EXACTLY the same hardware, but work arounds are being found. The general rule is: If your device isn't specifically listed do not install the ROM!

In your case here I'm sure it will brick the device as there is different hardware (buttons etc), a different model code, and a different partition structure.

Comment: Good answer, but debatable example. Latest CM10 and CM11 ROMs (and their derivatives) are now unified across all i9505 variants, which means the same ROM works on both 9505 and 9505G.

Comment: @Chahk Thanks, changed to I9500 and mentioned the Google Edition as an example that WAS true, but has been changed. That's a good development, thanks for lettine me know, hopefully the answer is a bit better now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost certain that you have to download the ROM for the exact device you are using. I tried to download the root file for another model of my Galaxy S4 (AT&T) not realizing that my version was different (T Mobile) and ended up bricking my phone. So it applies to ROMs as well. Find the exact model of your phone. I also had to go to "About Device" and match the baseband versions.